# .Net Application Runs Fine normaly, Breaks When Scheduled

Tags: .net, console-application, scheduled-tasks

I have a very simple .Net application which creates folders on a daily basis, usually I run it manually and have done for almost a year, yesterday I decided to schedule it to save time, when I ran into a problem we have been encountering for a long time now on our projects.

When the scheduled time arrives the application runs, but crashes, leaving only "the Specified Query is incorrect" on the Task Scheduler interface. I then run the exe manually and it works again, so next I try to run it manually through the Task Scheduler and it crashes once more.

I am running the scheduled task with highest privaledges and it operates on a server on our network, I am checking the connection is available etc. I have domain admin and cannot see for the life of me what is causing this to happen.

Any help would be great!

Comment: Can you post the exception message please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which account do it run on? NETWORK_SERVICE would be a good idea.

Exception details would also help.

Comment: plus has the account where the scheduler runs on has enough permissions to do the job-s task? Is there any gui/messagebox involved in the task that would be invilible?. Maybe you should start your task via runas + yourUserName.

Answer (score 0):

You need to log the error and do a diagnostics.Basically when you schedule an application make sure that no UI pops up etc so you need to pass arguments to make it run silently.You may need to change the code and try again.Also make sure you have added the necessary "" quotes that are needed sometimes in case of arguments and also specify the correct start up directory etc.